# Unable to access static file in Node express root folder

Tags: javascript, express

I am trying to create a file uploader which will store file in `stored_images` directory as shown below:

```
/project
  /bin
  /stored_images
  /routes
  /public
```

After the file has been saved here, I want to send url of the saved file to my front-end javascript. How can I get the url of file in stored in `stored_images` directory?? Or is there other better way to do this??

Answer (score 1):

First tell express where to look for static files.

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Then put you images folder in your public folder. Then the url to your images would be the path from within the public folder to your images.

For example `/my_images/cool_pic`.

Comment: Or `app.use('/stored_images', express.static('stored_images'))`